# Can I store something to file in a ScheduledTaskAgent?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I want to run something every couple of days, so I need the ScheduledTaskAgent each time it runs to check the date and if the diff is >3 days it should do something.

But how can I store a date to a file in a ScheduledTaskAgent and later read and update it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, [here is the list of unsupported APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202962%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) when using agents.

Comment: Could you explain on the how part? Could i just open a filestream to date.txt and read write?

Comment: yup, just like any other operation on the isolated storage ;) here is a good article explaining how to open/read/write on files: http://www.jeffblankenburg.com/2010/10/15/31-days-of-windows-phone-day-15-isolated-storage/